# Why is my third float element appearing in the next line, even though I applied border-box to it?

Tags: html, css

I want three blocks of text, each in its own section tag, to float next to each other, with sufficient margins and padding in between, but the third block of text keeps showing up below the first block instead. I used the following CSS code for that:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
section{
   position: relative;
   width: 33.3%;
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid black; 
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: because the margin and padding also border of section

Comment: But ```box-sizing: border-box``` should include those extra pixels in the total width, right?

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` subtracts both the padding and the border from the total width but not the margin. You can use calc to subtract the margins: `width: calc(33.33% - 20px)`. There is unfortunately no such thing as `box-sizing: margin-box`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying `box-sizing: border-box` the padding and borders are included in the total width, but not the margins. You can use calc to subtract the margins: `width: calc(33.33% - 20px)`. There is unfortunately no such thing as `box-sizing: margin-box`.

This should work:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: calc(33.3% - 20px); /* left and right margin subtracted*/
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black; 
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Also, consider flexbox or grid for your layouts. Floats are a bit outdated to use as a general layout mechanism and should be used for their intended use: text-wrapping around elements.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `padding`,`margin` and `border` from width by using **calc()** in CSS.

Here, margin:10px, padding:10px and border:1px;

So it both in left and right so its double

try this

```
width: calc(33.3% - (20px + 20px + 2px));
```

instead of

```
 width: 33.3%;
```

That is

```
section{
   position: relative;
   width: calc(33.3% - (20px + 20px + 2px));
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black; 
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Remove `box-sizing:border-box` because,

> The **box-sizing** property allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height.If you set `box-sizing: border-box;` on an element, **padding** and **border** are included in the width and height:

**`box-sizing` - Defines how the width and height of an element are calculated: should they include padding and borders, or not**

### **`Working Demo`**

```css
*,html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
section{
   position: relative;
   width: calc(33.3% - (20px + 20px + 2px)) !important;
   float: left !important;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black; 
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<section>section1</section>
<section>section2</section>
<section>section3</section>
```

Comment: Hey, but if you do this, there would be a lot of extra space on the right. I want the margin on the left and that on the right to be the same.

Comment: ok give me 2 min

Comment: box-sizing: border-box; on an element, padding and border are included in the width and height:

Comment: !important is evil. It breaks the natural css specificity flow. Do not use it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css) answer.

Comment: Please add extra class to the section and **section.classname** and remove **!important**.